# Src layout to dispense .src prefix in imports? Activate venv in PyCharm terminal for development installs

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, setuptools, setup.py

I want to understand what is considered the correct minimalist way to use setuptools with a ["src/ layout"](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-a-src-layout) in a way that dispenses using `src.` prefix in imports?

I have read most of the [PyPA](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials) and [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io) documentation (and its many use cases), but I can't understand what is considered the correct way of doing this example.

The below layout reproduces what I want to achieve. I can't understand how to get the second import to work instead of the first across all modules of the `mylibrary` package:

```py
from src.mylibrary.hello_word import hello_function # <- This works.
from mylibrary.hello_word import hello_function  # <- How to get this working?

hello_function()
```

Using this directory/file structure:

```
C:\MyProject
│
│   setup.py
│
└───src
    │
    ├──mylibrary
    │      hello_word.py
    │      module_two.py
    │      __init__.py
    │
```

When I use [development mode](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-a-local-src-tree) install with `pip install -e .` the egg directory is added to the above tree:

```
    │ (...)
    │ 
    └──mylibrary.egg-info
           dependency_links.txt
           PKG-INFO
           SOURCES.txt
           top_level.txt
```

With this `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, find_namespace_packages

setup(
    name='mylibrary',
    version='0.1',
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    # packages=find_namespace_packages(where='src'),  # <- I suppose this isn't the deciding factor.
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
)
```

The simple `hello_world.py` module that I want to dispense having to write `src.` when importing.

```py
def hello_function():
    print("hello world")
```

The `__init__.py` is left empty.

I'm using a venv, to my surprise the egg symlink isn't written to the venv `sitepackages` but to `C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages`...

Python console indicates `mylibrary` package is found:

```sh
>>> from setuptools import find_packages
>>> find_packages(where='src')
['mylibrary']
```

Comment: You have already installed the package in development mode, this should be enough. Sometimes reinstalling is necessary, but only when you add/remove sources to/from the project or change the package metadata. _the egg symlink isn't written to the venv sitepackages_ - this is probably the root issue, what does `pip -V` return? Does it point to venv's site? Is the package in the list of installed packages (what does `pip show mylibrary` yield)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem described results from having to [activate the venv inside PyCharm's terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288569).

A description of the scenarios you'll likely encounter follows. (The problem isn't immediately obvious because unlike the terminal, functionalities like debugging, running, etc, integrate the venv in a seamless way.)

It should be noted:

- Using the verbose flag `-v` while installing in [development mode](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-a-local-src-tree) gives clues to what *pip* and *setuptools* are trying to do.
- The decisive *pip* messages are based on write permissions of your `site-packages`, however you won't have to change any of the default permission if activating your venv on the terminal.
- If you are using 1 venv, there will be 3 different `site-packages` involved (mind the paths).

The 3 options you are likely to try:

**Option 1.** Run *PyCharm* as admin, executing the following from the terminal gives:

```sh
C:\MyProject>pip install -v -e .

Non-user install because site-packages writeable
(...)
Creating c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\mylibrary.egg-link (link to src)
```

This installs to `site-packages` (mind the path) in your base Python installation. Something you likely want to avoid, because it pollutes your base installation.

**Option 2.** Run *PyCharm* as user. **Without activating venv on the terminal.**

```
C:\MyProject>pip install -v -e .

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
(...)
Creating c:\users\name\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages\mylibrary.egg-link (link to src)
```

This installs to `site-packages` (mind the path) outside your venv, and outside your Python base installation. Something you likely want to avoid, because *PyCharm* won't recognize the development installation after it's done.

NOTE: The message in the terminal "(...) site-packages is not writeable" refers to the `site-packages` in your Python base instalation. But, without explicitly activating the venv, even if you set the permissions to writeable, the development instalation won't write to your venv `site-packages`.

**Option 3.** Run *PyCharm* as user. **Activating venv on the terminal.**

```sh
(MyProject_venv) C:\MyProject>pip install -v -e .

Non-user install because user site-packages disabled
(...)
Creating c:\myproject_venv\lib\site-packages\mylibrary.egg-link (link to src)
```

Here you did write to `site-packages` in your venv, which is likely what you want.

Answer (score 3):

### Update / Workaround

One can follow the steps in [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html) to mark a folder as a `source root`. From the link:

> Source roots the Source root icon contain the actual source files and
> resources. PyCharm uses the source roots as the starting point for
> resolving imports

This way we don't have to install It or to change the path anymore (although It still feels kind of tricky to me)

#### 1. Pycharm has a `pip` problem:

Whenever I run `pip` in the pycharm terminal It runs the system's `pip` for some reason. You can check that with the `which pip` command. But if I run `python -m pip` It does the right thing.

#### 2. It should actually recognizes the imports:

That being said, I really don't know why pycharm can't recognize the imports without the `src.` prefix. I cloned the `cryptography package from github and It recognizes It normally, the src folder is automatically added to path, but I don't know how Yet.

Either way, your code works as expected without the prefix and Vim (using Pyright) recognizes It flawlessly. Even running It on pycharm actually works with all the import errors.

#### 3. What to do now?

Until they fix It or I find a solution I'll just add the src folder to my path in the interpreter settings manually, since I don't want to install It (but I want to be able to peak and go to definitions).

If I really want to install the package I would do It in the terminal or inside pycharm using `python -m pip install -e -v .`