# setup.py - how to set a sub-folder as the main package directory?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

My project structure:

```
/myproject/       <- I would like to skip that folder
  /mypackage/
    /subpackage/
      mymodule.py
    run.py
- setup.py
```

Within `run.py` I'd like to import from `mymodule.py` like that:

```
from mypackage.subpackage.mymodule import something
```

instead of:

```
from myproject.mypackage.subpackage.mymodule import something
```

Is there a way in `setup()` to define the entrypoint as being `mypackage` and skip `myproject`?

Comment: You want `package_dir = 'myproject'` if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: You might find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62498127) interesting.

Comment: @Iguananaut thanks, that's it. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use what's called a src-layout (since `src/` is more typically used as a top-level directory for packages.  See https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-a-src-layout

If using `setup.cfg` you can write this like:

```
[options]
package_dir=
    =src
packages=find:

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

or equivalently, using an old-style `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
setup(
...
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
    packages=find_packages(where='src')
...
)
```

packages

Comment: New link for documentation: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#using-a-src-layout