# Python can't import library installed using pip venv

Tags: windows, virtualenv, python-3.7, sys, python-venv

I've looked at several posts and articles and I can't seem to find a solution to this. I need to use jenkspy for a specific task but my Python3x was installed with a software called ArcGIS Pro that designates the default python environment "Read Only" meaning that packages not installed with it must be installed in a virtual environment.

So, I opened command line and ran:

```
py -m venv env
py -m pip install jenkspy --user
```

If I continue to run python from command window I can import jenkspy no problem. However, when I attempt to import it in iPython or load it into pythonWin as a script I get:

```
import jenkspy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jenkspy'
```

So I go back to command window and run python to locate path for jenkspy:

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
```

which returns:

```
['', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\Lib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64', 'C:\\Users\\johnsmith\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I navigate to the native idle.py file in this environment and import jenkspy. No problem. I print sys.path from the idle console. Same result as in command line.

I then go back to iPython and run:

```
import sys
paths = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\Lib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64', 'C:\\Users\\johnsmith\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib\\site-packages']

for p in paths:
    sys.path.append(p)
```

and then:

```
import jenkspy
```

And I get this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-88ab181dc114> in <module>
----> 1 import jenkspy

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jenkspy\__init__.py in <module>
      3 __version__ = "0.1.5"
      4 
----> 5 from .core import jenks_breaks
      6 
      7 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jenkspy\core.py in <module>
      7     from math import isinf, isnan
      8     isfinite = lambda x: not isinf(x) and not isnan(x)
----> 9 from . import jenks
     10 try:
     11     import numpy as np

ImportError: cannot import name 'jenks'
```

What do I need to do in order to get jenkspy or other post python installation packages/modules to be imported using stand alone scripts and or/iPython?

Comment: You didn't mention activating the venv. The following sequence of commands work for me:- `python -m venv venv, .\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1, python -m pip install jenkspy, python, import jenkspy`

Comment: [This solution will probably work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62498127/).