# unittest runs in terminal but not in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

I have the following project structure and I am working with remote deployment with Pycharm.

```
source/
+- src/  
   +- __init__.py
   +- abcd.py
+- test/
   +- __init__.py
   +- tests.py
```

In tests.py, I import src.abcd.
Running unittest in terminal with `python -m unittest test.tests` in the `source` folder is OK. But when I run the unittest in Pycharm, it says `No module named 'src.abcd'`.
If I remove the `__init__.py` in `source/test` folder, Pycharm is OK but terminal reports error `No module named 'test/tests'`.

Is there anyway to run unittest with both the commandline and Pycharm?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't know the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: You say: "If I remove the `__init__.py` in `source/test` folder, Pycharm is OK" -- is this really true?  Is it just running 0 tests?

Comment: Consider making an [installable package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62498127).

Comment: Sorry I missed some information that I thought is unimportant. There is a `__init__.py` in the `source` folder and the `source` folder has the same name with the `src`. So I think it is because Pycharm is confused by the folder names. I changed the folder name of `src` and the problem is solved!